# Storing distance data from HealthKit causes a crash "Fatal error: Can't remove last element from an empty collection"

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to build an array with a list of distance values read from HealthKit, but each time I try to run the app, it crashes with the following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Can't remove last element from an empty collection

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit

struct SetupView: View {
    private var healthStore: HealthStore?
    @State private var distances: [Distance] = [Distance]()
    
    init(){
        healthStore = HealthStore()
    }
    
    private func updateUIFromStats(_ statsCollection: HKStatisticsCollection) {
        let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())!
        let endDate = Date()
        
        statsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: endDate){
            (statistics, stop) in
            let count = statistics.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.mile())
            let distance = Distance(count: Double(count ?? 0), date: statistics.startDate)
            distances.append(distance)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(distances, id:\.id) { distance in
            VStack{
                Text("\(distance.count)")
                Text(distance.date, style: .date).opacity(0.8)
            }
        }
            .onAppear{
                if let healthStore = healthStore{
                    healthStore.requestAuth{ success in
                        if success {
                            healthStore.calcDistance { statisticsCollection in
                                if statisticsCollection == statisticsCollection {
                                    updateUIFromStats(statisticsCollection!)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

struct SetupView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SetupView()
    }
}
```

I have been able to identify the offending line of code to be this:

```
distances.append(distance)
```

I think it has something to do with how I initialized the array, maybe it shouldn't be empty? But I am not sure. Any help would be greatly aprpeciated.

Here's my HealthStore class below

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit

extension Date {
    static func mondayAt12AM() -> Date {
        return Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
                .date(from: Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date()))!
    }
}

class HealthStore {
    var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
    var query: HKStatisticsCollectionQuery?
    
    init(){
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        }
    }
    
    func calcDistance(completion: @escaping (HKStatisticsCollection?)-> Void){
        let distanceType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)!
        
        let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())!
        
        let anchorDate = Date.mondayAt12AM()
        let daily = DateComponents(day: 1)
        let watchPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withDeviceProperty: HKDevicePropertyKeyModel, allowedValues: ["Watch"])
        let samplePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
        let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
            [watchPredicate, samplePredicate])
        query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: distanceType, quantitySamplePredicate: compoundPredicate, options: .cumulativeSum, anchorDate: anchorDate, intervalComponents: daily)
        
        query!.initialResultsHandler = { query, statisticsCollection, error in
            completion(statisticsCollection)
        }
        
        if let healthStore = healthStore, let query = self.query {
            healthStore.execute(query)
        }
    }
    
    func requestAuth(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
//        let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
        let distanceType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)!
        let caloriesType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned)!
        let activityTimeType =  HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.appleExerciseTime)!
        let restHeartRateType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.restingHeartRate)!

        
        guard let healthStore = self.healthStore else { return completion(false)}
        
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [], read: [distanceType, caloriesType, activityTimeType, restHeartRateType]) {
            (success, error) in completion(success)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show complete code of this view?

Comment: Updated post to show full View code, and HealthStore class.

Answer (score 0):

Load the array in separate thread.

example:`DispatchQueue.main.async { salesDict.append(dict) }`